# How can I save a PDF from an URL with TWebbrowser in Delphi7 to a PDF FILE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

Is there a way to save a PDF from a TWebbrowser in Delphi 7 to a file?
I can display the PDF in the Webbrowser but How do I save it to a locally PDF FIle?

Answer (score 1):

You can save any webpage to a file with `TWebbrowser` like this:

```
Uses 
  ActiveX,
  ...

...

procedure TForm1.SaveDocument(AFilename : String);

var 
  Stream : TFileStream;
  StreamAdapter: IStream;
  PersistStreamInit: IPersistStreamInit;

begin
 if not Assigned(Browser.Document) then
  Exit;
 if Browser.Document.QueryInterface(IPersistStreamInit, PersistStreamInit) = S_OK then
  begin
   Stream := TFileStream.Create(AFilename, fmCreate);
   try
    StreamAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(Stream);
    PersistStreamInit.Save(StreamAdapter, True);
   finally
    Stream.Free;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I use Delphi 7 and the command Browser.SaveToStream does not exists.

Comment: I also found a routine, which save the HTML but no PDF. See here [link]http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1112 Can anyone explain why this routine doesnot save a PDF?

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair: yes my fault, SaveToStream line is not needed here. This code can save a PDF page? Can you edit your question and show us a complete example how you are trying to save the page?

Comment: No the code can not save a PDF. Still 0 byte on result file.

Comment: at what moment are you trying to save the file, right after the Navigate command?

Comment: no after the OnDocumentComplete is triggered. I can see the PDF in the Webbrowser. ANyway I found a solution with Eldos SecureBlackBox. But TWebbrowser would do all the JS stuff fine, and with ELDOS I must interpret the HTML also. But with Eldos I can save an URL to a stream. I really would like to know how it is done with TWebbrowser.

Comment: I did some tests and it seems that it is not possible because it is not the browser that is hosting the file but adobe reader?